# how to let container knows which day it is today

Tags: flutter

I want to highlight the container, when for example today is Monday, and then Monday container should be orange and rest grey.

here is my code, my thought is set each day as a bool, and then if e.g bool monday is true, and then monday color will be turned to orange, but now my question is i dont know where I should put my judgment... and do we have a smarter way to achieve my need instead of using switch..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'config.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Material(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  dateContainer(
                    text: "S",
                  ),
                  dateContainer(text: "M"),
                  dateContainer(text: "T"),
                  dateContainer(text: "W"),
                  dateContainer(text: "T"),
                  dateContainer(text: "F"),
                  dateContainer(text: "S"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  InkWell dateContainer({String text}) {
    final date = DateTime.now();
    final todayDate = DateFormat('EEEE').format(date);
    bool isToday = false;
    bool Sunday = false;
    bool Monday = false;
    bool Tuesday = false;
    bool Wednesday = false;
    bool Thursday = false;
    bool Friday = false;
    bool Saturday = false;


    switch (todayDate) {
      case 'Sunday':
      setState(() {
        Sunday = true;
      });
        break;
      case 'Monday':
        setState(() {
          Monday = true;
        });
        break;
      case 'Tuesday':
        setState(() {
          Tuesday = true;
        });
        break;
      case 'Wednesday':
        setState(() {
          Wednesday = true;
        });
        break;
      case 'Thursday':
        setState(() {
          Thursday = true;
        });
        break;
      case 'Friday':
        setState(() {
          Sunday = true;
        });
        break;
      case 'Saturday':
        setState(() {
          Saturday = true;
        });
        break;
    }

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print(text);
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isToday ? Colors.orange : Colors.black38,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
        height: 36,
        width: 36,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: smallTextBoldStyle(textColor: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Bro I have fixed your code and made it better
you don't need to repeat yourself that much when you code **(Dry Code)**

all you need to do is to compare each card value (Text) with the date.

**Results**

[image]

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    
    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
    }
    
    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Material(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      dateContainer(text: "Sunday"), //Pass the full Day
                      dateContainer(text: "Monday"),
                      dateContainer(text: "Tuesday"),
                      dateContainer(text: "Wednesday"),
                      dateContainer(text: "Thurday"),
                      dateContainer(text: "Friday"),
                      dateContainer(text: "Suturday"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      InkWell dateContainer({String? text}) {
        final date = DateTime.now();
        final todayDate = DateFormat('EEEE').format(date);

        //Because you already know what each card value is just 
        //check if card text is equal to the date value.
    
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print(text);
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: todayDate == text ? Colors.orange : Colors.black38,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
            height: 36,
            width: 36,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                text!.substring(0, 1),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using switch, you can check the color with this way:

```
color: todayDate == 'Monday' ? Colors.orange : Colors.black38,
```

this is the full answer code based on your question, dont forget to install package **intl: ^0.17.0** in your pubspec.yaml, so you can use DateFormat inside your code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final date = DateTime.now();
  final todayDate =  DateFormat('EEEE').format(date);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test'),),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: todayDate == 'Monday' ? Colors.orange : Colors.black38,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
        height: 36,
        width: 36,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'text',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: cool, that is the solution, thx!